# Can't view Chinese chars in evince or xpdf

Tags: debian, pdf, evince

Instead, I get white squares. I have no idea if they are used, but I installed "xfonts-intl-chinese" (didn't work). I googled this issue, and there was a lot of talk about some bug in poppler. But, that was so long ago so I should have the more recent version without the bug, right? I'm on Debian if that helps.

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to view a document produced on some other platform such as Windows that does not contain embedded fonts. Is this the case?

Comment: Some data after Alt-Return in evince: Foxit PDF Creator Version 2.0 ("Producer", at least if I were to translate what it says from Swedish), PDF-1.3 ("Format"). The title suggests it was originally an MS Word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian stable runs does not jump to newer versions of packages very quickly.

Poppler Versions:

- Debian Stable: 0.12.4 (2 yrs old)
- Debian Testing/Unstable: 0.16.7 (10 months old)
- Current Release: 0.18.4 (2 months old)
- Bleeding Edge: 0.19.3 (6 days old)

So you may be running to the bug in poppler you found by in your search.  I would try the Debian Testing (wheezy) release poppler packages.

Comment: Hello, I upgraded the whole system to "sid". I didn't know that was experimental so hopefully I didn't burn down the house to kill the rats... but, you were corretct - the text is now displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Synaptic package manager. Type "cmap-adobe-" in  the "Quick Search" text box. In the "Packages List" pane you should see the "gs-cjk-resource", "cmap-adobe-gb1" and "cmap-adobe-cns1" packages. Install those packages. You might have to install the "poppler-data" package also.

Comment: OK, this will look stupid with all on the same line but it seems the return key will trigger the "Save Edits" button? Anyway, thanks for the effort, but still the same... > aptitude search poppler-data cmap-adobe-cns1 cmap-adobe-gb1 gs-cjk-resource
i   cmap-adobe-cns1              - CMaps for Adobe-CNS1
i   cmap-adobe-gb1               - CMaps for Adobe-GB1
i   gs-cjk-resource              - Resource files for gs-cjk, ghostscrip
i A poppler-data                 - Encoding data for the poppler PDF